# Hibernate XML loading properties through join table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I currently have following tables:

**address**: addressID, ... , postalCode, countryCode
**countries**: countryCode, countryName (name_en column)
**postalcodes**: countryCode, postalCode, placeName (name_en column)

Now I want to load an address by it's ID
-> *countryName* from countries using countryCode
-> *placeName* from postalcodes using countryCode **and** postalCode

I've mapped address using Hibernate XML Mapping:

```
<class name="entity.Address" table="address">
<id name="addressID" type="java.lang.Integer" column="addressID">
    <generator class="identity" />
</id>

<property name="streetName" type="string" column="streetName"/>
<property name="streetNumber" type="string" column="streetNumber" />
<property name="countryCode" type="string" column="countryCode" />
<property name="postalCode" type="string" column="postalCode" />

<join table="countries">
    <key foreign-key="countryCode" column="countryCode" property-ref="countryCode"/>
    <property name="countryName" column="name_en"/>
</join>

<join table="postalcodes">
    <key foreign-key="postalCode" column="postalCode" property-ref="postalCode"/>
    <property name="placeName" column="placeName"/>
</join>

</class>
```

When I execute my code hibernate generates the following SQL:

```
Hibernate: select address0_.addressID as addressI1_0_0_, address0_.streetName as streetNa2_0_0_, address0_.streetNumber as streetNu3_0_0_, address0_.countryCode as countryC4_0_0_, address0_.postalCode as postalCo5_0_0_, address0_1_.name_en as name_en2_15_0_, address0_2_.placeName as placeNam2_16_0_ from address address0_ inner join z_countries address0_1_ on address0_.addressID=address0_1_.countryCode inner join z_postalcode address0_2_ on address0_.addressID=address0_2_.postalCode where address0_.addressID=?
```

I don't know if using join tables is the right approach, but the Hibernate SQL output needs following changes to get the result needed:

```
inner join z_countries address0_1_ on address0_.countryCode=address0_1_.countryCode 
inner join z_postalcode address0_2_ on address0_.countryCode=address0_2_.countryCode and address0_.postalCode=address0_2_.postalCode
```

I need to make the following changes to the map:

Joining the countries table using **countryCode** instead of **addressID**
Joining the postalcodes table using **countryCode AND postalCode** instead of **addressID**

I've spent the last couple hours trying to crack this without any result.
I've checked the examples on JBoss, searching for associations, join tables, but since these field arent entities, like Order & Customer, I cannot get this to work.
I assume that it must be something very simple and a small change.

Thanks in advance for the help, if you have any further questions regarding the matter, please ask.